# Using SQL Server query desired table output for the given table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a following table in SQL Server 2008 and it needs to be shown in a particular format. I was thinking of what approach should I follow to get desired output. Whether cursor needs to be used or not or multiple while loops to traverse each rows. This table has multiple accounts and dt_id is unique.

Kindly find the table below:

[image: Table A]

Desired output:

[image]

The problem statements is for eg in first table for first non zero `dt_debit` amount is 100 and I need to check whether this value cancels out in `dt_credit` column on FIFO method.

So in this case in first loop 100 gets compared to 500. So here it's less than
500 therefore it will go in the 2nd table.

Then it will go to 2nd value that is 400 and it will compare previous remaining balance that is 500 - 100 = 400 so again since its not greater again entry will go in desired output table.

Now for value 50 it will compare with 300 and 250 balance will be left. Next value is 300 therefore for 300 values will go twice as it will come in 250 + it will also take 50 from 80 `dt_credit`.

Can this logic be done in SQL Server. I am using SQL Server 2008. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just as a note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Comment: Oooo you get to learn the dark arts of recursive CTE's, which is what this scenario is calling for. Check this link and let us know when you get lost. https://www.essentialsql.com/recursive-ctes-explained/

Comment: 2nd table?   what 2nd table?

Comment: In your example output table, you have DT_ID bound to the rows with Credit in the first two rows, then Debit in the last three. It might be more consistent to say that credit is always first and debit second, as it's difficult to follow when the primary key is flipping back and forth.

In general terms, is there a reason you can't use SUM() or something like that and get aggregate results? If you need to represent a running balance in a transaction, you could probably order the rows by insert date and compare the balance change after each row.

Comment: Hey I dont need to calculate running balance. I have already done that using SUM() function. I want to check whether debit amount in getting cancelled out by credit values. The second table is the 2nd table I have mentioned below. The match found in credit column should come in with the respective debit line with which it cancelled out.